# Dynamic cast to derived type in operator<<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, dynamic-cast

I have a base class `Tag` and a child class `TagSet`, that inherits from `Tag`.

```
class Tag
{
  public:
    Tag(std::string);
    std::string tag;
};
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Tag &t);

class TagSet : public Tag
{
public:
    TagSet();
};
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &os, const TagSet &ts);
```

and their implementations

```
Tag::Tag(std::string t)
: tag(t)
{}

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Tag &t )
{
  os << "This is a tag";
  return os;
}

TagSet::TagSet()
: Tag("SET")
{}

std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &os, const TagSet &ts)
{
  os << "This is a TagSet";
  return os;
}
```

I want to include a third class `TagList` that has a member `std::vector<Tag*>`, which can hold either `Tag*` instances or `TagSet*` instances. I want to define the `<<` operator for `TagList` such that it uses the `Tag` version of `operator<<` if the element is a `Tag` or the `TagSet` version of `operator<<` if the element is a `TagSet`. This is my attempt:

```
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &os, const TagList &ts)
{
  for (auto t : ts.tags)
  {
    if (t->tag == "SET")
    {
      TagSet * tset = dynamic_cast<TagSet*>(t);
      os << *tset << ", ";
    }
    else os << t->tag << ", ";
  } 
}
```

The code crashes at runtime. I checked the `tset` pointer and it isn't null. Probably it's a bad cast.

What is the correct way to do this? Is the problem something to do with consts in the `operator<<` function? Other suggests for how to achieve this are welcome.

The rest of the `TagList` implementation is here for completeness:

```
class TagList
{
public:
    TagList(std::vector<Tag*> taglist);
    std::vector<Tag*> tags;
    typedef std::vector<Tag*>::const_iterator const_iterator;
    const_iterator begin() const { return tags.begin(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return tags.end(); }
};
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &os, const TagList &ts);
```

and

```
TagList::TagList(std::vector<Tag*> tagvec)
: tags(tagvec.begin(), tagvec.end())
{}
```

Comment: Maybe you can attach your test code to check how objects are allocated

Comment: The code should fail to compile; `dynamic_cast` cannot be used on non-polymorphic types. To improve your question, post a MCVE

Answer (score 5):

If I may suggest a different solution to the problem of outputting your `Tag` objects, then have only a single operator overload, for `Tag const&`, and then have that call a virtual `output` function in the `Tag` structure. Then override that function in the inherited classes.

Perhaps something like

```
struct Tag
{
    ...
    virtual std::ostream& output(std::ostream& out)
    {
        return out << "This is Tag\n";
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Tag const& tag)
    {
        return tag.output(out);
    }
};

struct TagSet : Tag
{
    ...
    std::ostream& output(std::ostream& out) override
    {
        return out << "This is TagSet\n";
    }
};
```

Then to output the list

```
for (auto t : ts.tags)
    std::cout << *t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, because `operator<<` is not virtual.

Define a virtual `print` method instead, and use that in `operator<<`, e.g.

```
class Tag {
public:
    virtual void print(std::ostream &f) const;
};

std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Tag &t)
{
    t->print(os);
    return os;
}
```

Now you can use method `print()` in `TagList` as well without any cast at all:

```
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &os, const TagList &ts)
{
    for (auto t : ts.tags) {
        t->print(os);
        os << ", ";
    }
}
```

or implicit

```
for (auto t : ts.tags) {
    os << *t << ", ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is essentially a hand-written RTTI with extra memory overhead. Mixing it with build-in RTTI by using dynamic cast won't work since classes `Tag` and `TagSet` are not polymorphic and build-in RTTI for objects of these types is not available at runtime to perform such cast. If you insist of using hand-written RTTI then you need to perform a `static_cast`.

```
TagSet & tset{static_cast<TagSet &>(*t)};
```